# Link redirection in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

This is a ColdFusion application that has many email functionalities embedded with specific application links.

Need to know how to store the target link in the application that doesn't change with the entire session.
Is it possible to use the target query in the link to redirect to the saved target link?

Sample code:
Page1 code

```
cfset objRequest = GetPageContext().GetRequest()

cfset strUrl = objRequest.GetRequestUrl().Append("?" & objRequest.GetQueryString()).ToString
```

All other pages will have the page1 loaded like this:

```
cfinclude template="../xxx/Page1.cfm"
```

so each time the page1 is loaded the `strUrl` value keeps changing. Need help to know where and how can I actually store the `strUrl` value on the first hit.

Comment: Show us some code so we can help you.

Comment: We definitely need more information to help you with this, and it's a big question - you're essentially asking us to develop for you. It might help if you asked a more specific question in the vein of your last paragraph.

From the little info provided, I might urge you to look into the APPLICATION scope. You can store variables there for the entire app, not just the session (which the SESSION scope handles).

Comment: Thanks for checking this. I have tried modifying the question and have added sample code.

Comment: You're getting `session` and `request` mixed up. Look at the Application scope like was mentioned. Take a look at all the scopes and what they do. http://www.learncfinaweek.com/week1/Scopes/